# Rxjs pipe call two times when have a service call with map inside map

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-services, rxjs6

I have  a below method to have a service call when using map inside map first time which goes to catchError and then automatically goes to response.

```
fetchProduct(): Observable<Model[]> {
    return this.http.get<DataModel[]>(Product_URL).pipe(
      map(res => {       
        return res.map((item: DataModel) => {
          return this.Mapper(item.code, item.name);
         });
      }),
       catchError(error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }
```

when i using without map , which call once .

```
fetchProduct(): Observable<Model[]> {
    return this.http.get<DataModel[]>(Product_URL).pipe(
      map(res => {       
       console.log(res);
      }),
       catchError(error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }
```

whats wrong with the first implementation why which calls twice

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Which version of Rxjs are you using

Comment: @Niladri, from what his syntax is, he's using Rxjs6

Comment: I am getting an array of objects and binding to the control , when i using two map which calls twice

Comment: @MohamedSahir what is this.Mapper?

Comment: @Niladri which us the function to map the response the properties `Mapper(code, description){
    return { id: code, name: description };
  }`

Comment: Provide a stackblitz

Comment: What does `this.handleError(error)` do? If possible, please add the code for that as well.